# SAS do-loop for creating variables

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

Let's say I have a bunch of variables (call it eq3_xxxxx where the xxx are the variations) that all have 5 possible levels (1,2,3,4,5) and I want to create a dummy variable for each level of each variable.

I thought I could do something like:

```
%macro eq_levels(eq3:);
data mydata;
%do i = 1 %to 5;
x=cats(%eq3:,%i);
%end;
%mend;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I'd rather not use SQL or anything like that, as I think the array and do-loop solutions should suffice, but I am open to it if the explanation can be made straightforward enough.

Comment: Did you try just using a CLASS statement? Do you really need to generate actual dummy variables?  There are procs that can do that for you.  Or try writing the code to handle one variable and its associated dummy vars first. Then think about how to convert to a macro that could generate that code for multiple input variables.

Comment: This article goes through a lot of the different options and the links at the end have more options.

Comment: You're not calling your macro.  You're mixing macro variables `%i` with non-macro variables `i` and it's not clear which you intended.  You probably don't need to wrap your entire data step in a macro call.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be some minor syntax problems you have. Is this what you want?

```
%macro eq_levels(eq3);
    data;
        do i = 1 to 5;
            x = cats(&eq3,i);
            output;
        end;
    run;
%mend;
%eq_levels("eq3_");
```

Output:

```
    i   x
1   1   eq3_1
2   2   eq3_2
3   3   eq3_3
4   4   eq3_4
5   5   eq3_5
```

Answer (score 0):

I am maybe misreading this, but I understand that OP wishes multiple variables:

```
%macro macro_evn;
    data mydata;
        %do i=1 %to 5;
        var&i=&i.;
        output;
    %end;
%mend;
%macro_evn;
```

Resulting to

```
var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 
1     .    .    .    . 
1     2    .    .    . 
1     2    3 
....
```

Which would be easy to fill as needed. Then again, maybe I misread the question.